# Failed loading /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/: with No Module description

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento

I am getting this error, I can't figure out why

I have a CentOS 6.8 Server using easyApache 4 VPS

How can I find out which module is not loading?

> Failed loading /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/: 
>   /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/: cannot read file
>   data: Is a directory

I have seen other posts but they all have module extensions attached to it. It seems that my modules are loading when I  `php -m` in the command line.
this is what it shows.

```
Failed loading /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/:  /opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/: cannot read file data: Is a directory
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
cgi-fcgi
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
filter
ftp
gd
hash
iconv
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
SimpleXML
soap
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

In php.ini under the extension_dir file I took out "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226" and I left it blank, to get it to load my site and the modules correctly.

> ; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
>
> extension_dir = ""

it also works if I do

> extension_dir ="/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/"

I have looked in my error_log and have no errors

But I do have issues with my site on the backend/admin and images on the frontend are not showing up.
here is the site if it helps
[www.patriciasouths.com](https://www.patriciasouths.com)

**Update**

I found out looking in apache error_log

mod_pagespeed was messing up my backend and images so I disable it until I can configure correctly.

**Solution**

I commented out the

> ;extension_dir = ""
>
> and
>
> ;zend_extension = ""

Apparently, in easyApache 4 allows you to use multiple PHP versions in case you have multiple websites that need different versions of PHP. It also has multiple .ini files which my modules were being loaded through another `.ini` so the extensions in the `php.ini` why were loading it twice which was conflicting (that's my guess)

Answer (score 0):

For my particular situation I had recently upgraded from 8.0 to 8.1 -- on Laravel 9 and my default ini settings were not matching PHP 8.0 to 8.1. I suspect it had something to do with the `max_execution_time` along with the `memory_limit` while attempting to run `php artisan queue:work`.

Made the changes, and jobs run successfully now.

Some settings to look out for in the PHP ini file are:

```
memory_limit: This setting defines the maximum amount of memory a script can allocate. If this limit is exceeded, it can cause a segmentation fault. Try increasing this value and see if the issue still occurs.

max_execution_time: This setting defines the maximum time a script can run before it is terminated. If this time is exceeded, it can also cause a segmentation fault. Try increasing this value and see if the issue still occurs.

error_reporting: This setting defines the level of error reporting that PHP displays. If this is set too high, it can cause performance issues and potentially a segmentation fault. Try reducing this value and see if the issue still occurs.

display_errors: This setting determines whether PHP errors are displayed to the user. If this is set to "On", it can cause performance issues and potentially a segmentation fault. Try setting this to "Off" and see if the issue still occurs.
```